# Keras save model terminates python

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to save Keras model , I am using below script but it terminates python.

```
model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model
```

Please refer to below screenshot of console when tried saving keras model, It terminates execution of python script and run button appear at right side top corner.

[image]
Can anyone help me here.

Comment: does it show any message before terminating ? otherwise it might be difficult to see why it does that.

Comment: @LucBlassel No it doesn't show anything, It terminates and I had to restart kernal to proceed further

Comment: save_weights can sometimes work when save doesn't. Have you tried that?